# Using a Raspberry Pi 4 as a Router between AWS VPC and in-house Network

Tags: amazon-web-services, routes, raspberry-pi, ip, amazon-vpc

We have a special on-premise router in our office, which connects to a VPN.
In this VPN there is a special IBM MQ server which we want to poll. The server provider
demands the usage of a special client for polling which only works on windows. Since the rest of our IT-infrastructure is @AWS, we want to have the windows machine, which is supposed to poll the queues, as an EC2 instance.

To enable the connection our idea was that we set up a Raspberry Pi in our office, which connects via OpenVPN to a Client VPN Endpoint. The traffic from the Raspi is getting routed into the subnet, where the EC2 instance lives. All the traffic that the Raspi is receiving on a specific port, gets forwarded to the in-house router.

Unfortunately, we are not able to send anything from the EC2 instance to the Raspi. Is it even possible to route traffic from a subnet back to a Client VPN Endpoint?

[image: Diagram of our infrastructure]

Comment: Why not use a site-to-site VPN or DX?

Comment: DX is pretty much overkill & we don't have a device that supports site-to-site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's entirely possible; this problem is probably in your subnetting and routing.

- Ensure that there is no overlap between the subnet CIDRs in your VPC, the VPN and the on-prem network.
- Ensure the EC2 instance has an entry in its routing table that routes traffic for the on-prem network back via the client VPN endpoint. You can do this at VPC level by configuring the VPC's routing tables, so it applies to all instances in the VPC.
- Ensure the Pi has IP forwarding enabled (`echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`)
- Ensure the Pi doesn't firewalling forwarded traffic (`iptables-save` or `iptables -L -v`)
- Ensure the Pi has a route to get traffic up to the VPC, though it sounds like you have this in place already.

Comment: Everything is configured according to your points. I thought it might be impossible, because the VPN Client Endpoint Network only supports NAT and not Routing. I tried it with an OpenVPN Server inside the subnet and its working, without changing the configuration.

Comment: This is supported by AWS CVPN via site-to-site, see here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/scenario-onprem.html

Comment: I know, but since we don't have a device supported by site-to-site, we tried our luck with VPN Client Endpoint & a Raspberry. So I assume it is not possible that way right?